# Check if filename matches particular pattern or not

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have many files in folder. and whenever there is any update in any file I Receive an event for that in my windows service application.

And I am looking for something by which I can validate the file with specific pattern. If it matches then only that file should be processed or else it should be ignored.

Something like this

```
if(File.Matches("genprice*.xml"))
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

> 1. genprice20212604.xml
> 2. genprice20212704.xml
> 3. price20212604.xml
> 4. genprice20212704.txt

From above only #1 and #2 should be processed others should be ignored.

Comment: If you receive an event, I imagine you're using the `FileSystemWatcher`. Have you tried adding a filter to it? Or is the situation not that simple?

Comment: @Llama Yes I am using FileSystemWatcher. but I can't restrict from there as my pattern will be dynamic and configurable and it can be anything. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can try with regular expressions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleAppRegex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] fileNames = new string[] { "genprice20212604.xml",
                                                "genprice20212704.xml",
                                                "price20212604.xml",
                                                "genprice20212704.txt"}; 
            Regex re = new Regex(@"genprice[^\.]*.xml");

            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                if (re.Match(fileName).Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems the solution. Added toLower() for case sensitive issue. and it works good.

Comment: Instead of toLower() try to use case insensitive Regex:
Regex re = new Regex(@"^([^|\n]*\|){17,17}[^|\n]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use Regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
```

```
var reg = new Regex(@"genprice\d{8}$");

var fileNamesFromFolder = Direcotory.GetFiles(" @Folder´s path ", "*.xml")
.Where(path => reg.IsMatch(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)))
.Select(Folder=>
         Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Folder));
```

```
foreach (var file in fileNamesFromFolder )
{

//Do something...

}
```